# create expand collapse image when scroll listview

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQaSm.jpg)

[image]

I want to create some applications with widget ListView. When you scrolling up, image at first index will be expanded, and if you scroll again, next image will be expanded again, and if you scrolling down, image will be collapsed again.

Is it possible to create this with flutter?

Comment: This is possible, but not with a `ListView`. Look into [`CustomScrollView`s](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomScrollView-class.html).

Comment: please look at this video from flutter team not exactly your need but its same. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dUhmWAz4C7Y&vl=en

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make SliverAppBar have an image as a background instead of a color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58970477/make-sliverappbar-have-an-image-as-a-background-instead-of-a-color)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but what i hopefully needed is, if we scrolling up, image at first index will expand, and after image fade out, next image index is same, until last index, and if we scrolling down again, all image list will collapse back